# Play to His Full Potential

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have a question about “to his full potential”:

> He told Golf World magazine that he hadn’t yet ***played to his full potential***, “and when that happens, it will be just me and Tiger.”
> <sub>Source: [NYT – Sports of the Times – *Nice Hole in One, but Nobody Is Close to Par With Woods*](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/04/11/sports/golf/11rhoden.html)</sub>

I’ve looked in dictionaries and cannot find the phrase “to one's full potential”.  Could this be an error, or could it just happen not to be in dictionaries?

Comment: I don't think this is a set phrase. Dictionary definitions of *full* and *potential* should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

According to Macmillan:

> **realize/reach your (full) potential**
>
> achieve the most that you are capable of
>
> *As a composer, she still hasn't realized her potential.*
> <sub>Source: [macmillandictionary.com – potential – definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/potential_6)</sub>

In the context of that NYT article, Poulter is saying that once he finishes improving his golf play (once he’s as good as he believes he is capable of getting) he’ll be on par with Tiger Woods (above everyone else).

---

<sub>As far as searching for definitions goes, make sure you’re not too specific with your query and try looking for different pairs of words within a confusing passage. I found the definition above by searching: `define "full potential"`.</sub>

Comment: So, "*to one's full potential*" is a nonstandard variation of "*reach/realize one's full potential*"?

Comment: I guess that’s a decent way of looking at it, and that claim would seem to be bolstered by finding one in a dictionary and not the other. I think that most phrases as long and loosely fixed as this one will experience a lot of variation. “**<Verb> (up) to** one’s full potential” is probably [about as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reach+one%27s+full+potential%2Cto+one%27s+full+potential&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) as “**reach/realize** one’s full potential”.